# Is there a function in C language to calculate degrees/radians?

Tags: c

I need to calculate an angle in C programm. Here is a method from JAVA that I need to convert to C.

```
private static double calculateDirection(double x, double y)
{
    return Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(y, x));
}
```

Is there a function like toDegrees in C language so I don't have to write all the code by myself?
Thank you

Comment: I heard that C implements atan with signed division based on a sign of y. So, there is no need to act smart, although it looks trivial. thank you

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
#include <math.h>

inline double to_degrees(double radians) {
    return radians * (180.0 / M_PI);
}
```

Comment: ¸It doesn't find M_PI although include math.h is there? Any ideas

Comment: Some math.h don't get M_PI defined. Add `#ifndef M_PI #define M_PI 3.1415926535 #endif` to 'fix' that @AntunTun

Comment: It may help to `#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES` before all included headers.

Answer (score 8):

There is no need to use such a method. Converting to degrees is very simple:

```
double radians = 2.0;
double degrees = radians * 180.0 / M_PI;
```

Turn that into a function if you want to.

`M_PI` is* defined in `math.h` by the way.

---

* in most compilers.

Comment: It would still be best practice to this into a function, though.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Well, I'm not going to do _all_ the work for him.

Comment: I'd sooner write a macro for this.

Answer (score 5):

If your preference is to just copy/paste a couple of macros:

```
#include <math.h>
#define degToRad(angleInDegrees) ((angleInDegrees) * M_PI / 180.0)
#define radToDeg(angleInRadians) ((angleInRadians) * 180.0 / M_PI)
```

And if you want to omit the `#include`, replace that line with this which was copied from the `math.h` header:

```
#define M_PI   3.14159265358979323846264338327950288
```