# How to call a void function in C

Tags: c, function, call, void

Ok so I have written this code with four different functions, and the main purpose of it is to display in a table from angles 0-90 what the angle, time, distance of a velocity is. the velocity is inputed from the user.
But when I call the void function that is making the function I get an error "undefined reference to `create_table'" Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define G 9.8   /* gravitation acceleration 9.8 m/s^2 */
#define PI 3.141592654

void create_table(double v);
double Projectile_travel_time(double a, double v);
double Projectile_travel_distance(double a, double v);
double degree_to_radian(double d);

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    double velocity;

    printf ("please enter the velocity at which the projectile is launched (m/sec): ");
    n = scanf("%lf" ,&velocity);

    if(n != 1)
    {
        printf("Invlid input. Bye...");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (velocity < 0 )
    {
        printf ("please enter a positive number for velocity: ");
        n = scanf("%lf", &velocity);
        if(n != 1)
        {
            printf("Invlid input. Bye...");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    create_table(velocity);


    return 0;
}
  void create_table(double v)
    {
        printf("Angle      t      d\n");
        printf("(deg)    (sec)   (m)\n");

        double a,i;
        for( a=0; a<=90; a+=5)
        {
            for(i=0; i<=2; i++)
            {
                double t = Projectile_travel_time(a, v);
                double s = Projectile_travel_distance(a, v);
                printf("%d       %d       %d\n", a, t, s);

            }
        }


    }
    double Projectile_travel_time(double a, double v)
    {
        double t = ((2*v*sin(degree_to_radian(a)))/(G));
        return t;
    }
    double Projectile_travel_distance(double a, double v)
    {
        double d = ((v*v)/G)*sin(2*degree_to_radian(a));
        return d;
    }

    double degree_to_radian(double d)
    {
         double r = d*atan(1) * 4 / 180;
         return r;
    }
```

any help would be appreciated. 
thanks

*edit* I have edited the code but now have encountered another problem with my outputs being completely off. Any suggestions how my functions are incorrect?

Comment: you have to define the functions outside ofmain ..

Answer (score 1):

You must keep the functions you create outside of the main function

Comment: thanks! But now I am getting completly wrong numbers. Any idea what could be wrong in my functions?

Comment: no, I dont think that is the problem, because velocity just gets written as whatever the user enters.

Comment: Btw you can make a code maybe little more readable- eg. degree to radian is (degree/pi) *180

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920675/is-there-a-function-in-c-language-to-calculate-degrees-radians

#include <math.h>

inline double to_degrees(double radians) {
    return radians * (180.0 / M_PI);
}

:)

For pow you can use Math.pow, etc

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the function definitions out of `main`. C does not support [nested functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_function).

**Edit:** That is, in [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html) they are, but it's not portable.

Comment: thanks! But now I am getting completly wrong numbers. Any idea what could be wrong in my functions?

Comment: Try to debug them, and if you don't find out, ask a new question focusing just on the part you don't understand.

Comment: thanks, do you know why in the for loop even though I increment a by 5 but once I print the value for a I get 0 for all 19 times.

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement your functions outside the main()

Comment: thanks! But now I am getting completly wrong numbers. Any idea what could be wrong in my functions?

Comment: Check out of bound values and try pasting the input values and expected output values here.

Comment: velocity is uninitialized and you use it as a paramater, as it is a local variable it can contain any garbage number.

Answer (score 1):

> I have edited the code but now have encountered another problem with my outputs being completely off.

Change

```
printf("%d       %d       %d\n", a, t, s);
```

to

```
printf("%lf       %lf      %lf\n", a, t, s);
```

You can use `%7.3f` to align all the values.

Answer (score 0):

> Write all the function definitions `create_table`, `Projectile_travel_time`, `Projectile_travel_distance` and `degree_to_radian` outside the main.

Linker is not able to find the definition of `create_table` at the point at which you are calling `create_table`.