# C - Equivalent of Lua's math.rad

Tags: c, math, lua

I'm currently working on convertering some Lua script to C, and I've struggled upon some code:

```
markerCoords.x = playerCoords.x - ( sin(math.rad(camRot.z)) * 20 );
markerCoords.y = playerCoords.y + ( cos(math.rad(camRot.z)) * 20 );
```

I've looked online but I can't seem to find an equivalent of Lua's `math.rad` in C.

The description of this math function is as follows:

> #### [math.rad (x)](https://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/math.rad)
>
> Returns the angle x (given in degrees) in radians.

What is the equivalent of Lua's `math.rad` in C?

Comment: If you done basic school trigonometry you should know how to convert an angle from degrees to radians (and the opposite way). Using that it should be extremely easy to create such a function yourself. In short, no there's no such standard function, but it's easy to create your own.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a function in C language to calculate degrees/radians?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920675/is-there-a-function-in-c-language-to-calculate-degrees-radians)

Comment: @OmG there is *an* answer there, but the question is not duplicate

Comment: @AnttiHaapala It is the most related action that I could do. How can I vote to close the post in another way?

Comment: @OmG the problem is that the question asks how to convert degrees to radians.

Comment: It's quite simple. Just add `#include <math.h>` and the function `double deg2rad(double degrees) { return degrees / 180.0 * M_PI; }`.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage `M_PI` is specified by POSIX, but not by the C standard. Depending on your implementation and compiler options, it may not be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a standard function to do that in C, but as shown in this Q&A

[Is there a function in C language to calculate degrees/radians?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920675/is-there-a-function-in-c-language-to-calculate-degrees-radians)

It can be done with an user defined function

```
// Make sure to have the (non standard) M_PI defined
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>

#ifndef M_PI
#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288
#endif

// Apply basic trigonometry
inline double rad_from_deg(double degrees)
{
    return degrees * M_PI / 180.0;
}

inline double deg_from_rad(double radians)
{
    return radians * 180.0 / M_PI;
}
```